# Getting error while installing a Microsoft.AspNet.MVC Nugut package on window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

while installing  Microsoft.AspNet.MVC package I am getting following error. Any fix !

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3' was restored using
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
> '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
> with your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package is problem in [PusherClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PusherClient/). For solution refer   [scenarios 2 and 3 in NuGet wiki.](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Improved-NuGet-warnings)